# Our application needs to get informed when an event is created/deleted/ updated from Google Calendar Account rather than our Application

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, gdata-api

I have built an application that makes use of the GoogleCalendar Java client API.
Our application needs to get informed when an event is created/deleted/updated from Google Calendar Account rather than our Application (like RSS feeds..etc). Please guide us in this case to solve/overcome this issue.

Thanks and regards,
Amar

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get a feed of this information.  The Java client API is wrapping a REST API, and a REST API has no way of notifying a client of an event.

My recommendation is polling and looking for changes.  Also see [this](http://www.amicontech.com/blog/google-calendar-component-using-google-api/).